# "would like to see being removed" or "would like to be seen removed"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases

Let's say I let a room to a person and offer this person to remove stuff from this room if necessary. Could I say

```
"Please let me know if there is something you would like to see being removed"
```

or

```
"Please let me know if there is something you would like to be seen removed"
```

Are these sentences correct and if not how would I say that correctly? I am not interested in totally rephrasing the sentence from the above, but in using correct grammar with phraseology as close as possible to this particular structure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks for the comment. As written, I don't want to rephrase the sentence but was interested in the correct grammar; the sentence just served as an example.

Comment: The first variant is grammatical, but would normally be taken to imply that the lessee might be a keen removals watcher. The second variant is arguably grammatical but sounds weird to my ears. "??There is something I'd like to be seen removed. (... I'd like you to see (is) removed)". But I'd say this latter resists passivisation. //   "Please let me know if there is anything you'd like me to take out of the room." is idiomatic, as is DJClayworth's suggestion. Notice that 'see' doesn't have the 'make certain' sense with his variant, but the 'experience some event' sense.

Comment: The first variant is not grammatical in the context that is given. When interpreted in a way so that the grammar is correct, the semantic value of the sentence changes to contradict the speakers actual intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "something you would like to see being removed"

implies that they might want to watch the process of it being removed (i.e. continuous present)

> "something you would like to be seen removed"

is not grammatical. "be seen" is passive. If someone wants to "be seen" then it means they want someone else to see them doing something or in some condition. You might say they want to "be seen removing something", which implies that someone might watch them as they take something away.

You are probably looking for:

> **"Is there something you would like to see removed?".**

A little weird, as obviously if it is removed they won't see it, but it's what people say.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks! I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Answer (score 0):

Neither version of "See" belongs in that sentence.
[See means "Look at" or "observe"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:see)

So your sentences literally mean: "Do you want to **watch me** remove things?"

When you really want to ask: "Do you want me to remove things?"

Removing "See" may also help you realize that ["to be"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:be) is not relevant. 
A person does not "be something removed", a person "has something removed".

"Please let me know if there is something you would like to have removed."

"Please let me know if you would like me to remove something."

Comment: Can one not use "see" in a metaphorical sense?! Thanks for the comments about "to be" and also the alternatives. I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Comment: 'See' has a lot of other senses, including: **see** _verb_ (MAKE CERTAIN)
C2 [+ (that)] to make ​certain that something ​happens:
The ​receptionist said he'd see (that) she got the ​message. [+ see N Adj: _I'll see you dead!_] {[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see)}. This is relevant here (though possible ambiguity also needs mentioning).

Comment: 1) "See" does have symbolic usages.... all of which are idiomatic and should be avoided unless they are already your vocabulary.
2) All metaphoric uses of see are rooted in "Look at", "observe", and "confirm visually".
The examples @EdwinAshworth cites are using a metaphoric meaning of "I will make certain of this by visually confirming it for myself".
Therefore whether used literally or metaphorically, "to see removed" means "Do you want to visually observe or confirm that I have removed these things?". This is very different from saying "to have removed".